# How can I revoke an applications access to keychain passwords from the command-line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, keychain

Applications can be granted permanent unprompted access to passwords. You can add and revoke these privileges using the Keychain Access utility.  (See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104972/43372))

I'd like to be able to revoke from the command-line. Is this possible?

Specifically, my problem is that I'm creating a password in a shell script and storing it in the keychain using the `security add-generic-password ...` command. This works fine, but because the `security` application created the password, it's automatically granted free reading privileges. I want it to prompt every time.